# dynamically loading a page into HTML

Tags: javascript

I have web application which is comprised of an `index.html` file which includes an `<iframe>`. The `index.html` file loads different pages in the `<iframe>`. Each of those pages is has its own independent Javascript and CSS.

Everything works so far.

I am now thinking about loading those pages using Ajax calls into a `<div>`in the index.html instead of loading them into an `<iframe>`. I have done some tests and it is possible but there is an issue that worries me and since I'm new to this technique I thought maybe some experts here can share knowledge.

**Issue #1:**

When loading those pages directly to a `<div>` in the `index.html` file, the new page loads into the same DOM as the `index.html` itself. Therefore there can be conflicts between element classes and IDs of the page and hosting `index.html` for example `$("#foo").hide();` from the page will actually hide the elements with class `foo` in the `index.html` file as well as the page. Is there any way, I can put the page code in some sort of sandbox preventing it from affecting `index.html`?

**Issue #2:**

When removing a page (possibly to replace it with another page), there is a risk part of its code will still stay in the memory ([as mentioned here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml)). Is there any way to prevent this effect? Of course a positive answer to the first issue will cover this one
because if the page runs in a sandbox, unloading the page should unload its javascript code as well.

**Issue #3:**

The page is a complete HTML file with its own `<head>`, `<body>` and `<title>`elements. That means it is going to be affected with the CCS rules from the hosting `index.html` file as well. How can I prevent these negative side effects?

The paged-navigation system without requiring to reload the whole page seems to be a common interaction mechanism for many modern web sites. How is it possible to load a page dynamically without those side effects (without `<iframe>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about sounds like a single-page-app.  In which case I would recommend going with one of the many existing frameworks that address all the issues you are facing.

There are several in existence, these are just a couple.

Knockout.js ([knockoutjs.com](http://www.knockoutjs.com))

Ember.js ([emberjs.com](http://www.emberjs.com)
)

Comment: thanks for mentioning those two libraries. Are there more libraries I need to investigate before choosing one? Is backbone.js an option for example?

Comment: Yes backbone.js is another(very popular) option.  It is a little more barebones than the two mentioned above, but is very powerful if you pair it with a templating engine such as handlebars.js

Comment: I'm quite new to Javascript. I took a quick look at handlebars.js and it sounds interesting. Are there other template engines that I need to be aware of for making the right choice? Thanks.

Comment: Yes and no.  Knockout, Ember, and most other similar frameworks have their own templating engines while Backbone does not come with one.  As far as I can tell handlebars is pretty much the way to go there, though I haven't done a ton of research into other ones.  Some Google work will surely turn up comparison tables/blog posts that will help you decide which one is right for you, but ultimately you would probably be fine with any of them.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't inject pages that have side effects into your page safely.**

You will have to write your code in a style that doesn't rely on global state, which I presume is a lot of work.

In principle this means:

- No global variables in your JavaScript code
- Styling all contents using a class-name or unique ids, never by tag name.
- It is your responsibility to maintain the uniqueness of class names and ids, either through code in the form of templating languages or doing this manually.

To give you an example, you could give the internal div an id of `"page-container"` and mutate all of your css rules for the page, so that they are all prefixed with the `#page-container` selector.

Failing this, web app frameworks are commonly used to write single page web applications, and clearly demonstrate an ability to solve the issues you mention. It will however mean a lot of restructuring of your existing code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

As you may decide that moving to a fully-fledged new framework (mentioned in a parallel answer) may be an overkill, I'm posting an answer with some considerations a-la-carte.

**Issue #1:**

Once you load new content into the hosting page directly, there is no sandboxing possible. You need to elaborate a naming convention which prevents conflicts between IDs. For example, all elements in dynamically loaded fragments should have IDs with a specific prefix.

**Issue #2:**

You are responsible for clean up in all aspects that was involved during loading.

**Issue #3:**

It's not good idea to place into divs dynamically loaded fragments with their own heads, bodies and titles. You should load a pure content. And you don't have an option to prevent hosting page's CSS from affecting new fragments, unless you again elaborate a naming conventions for your CSS styles (classes).